# How can I scroll an overflowed DIV all the way to the left?

Tags: css

I currently have a div that is 100% width as a main content area on a mobile site. I'm using it as a window for a div underneath which can be an arbitrary width. (from 200px to 1000px). I have set

```
overflow: scroll;
width: 100%;
```

on the window DIV.

I want to be able to scroll the child DIV as long as it is larger than the main/window DIV. Since the main/window DIV is on a mobile device, it's difficult to know the width.

I can't set a width on the child DIV as I have no idea what its width will be. I can use Javascript to get that width before the page is rendered though.

my layout looks like this:

```
+-------------------+-------------+
|                   |             |
|        Scrollable Content       |
+-------------------+-------------+
                    |             |
                    |             |
                    |             |
                    | WINDOW DIV  |
                    |             |
                    |             |
                    |             |
                    |             |
                    |             |
                    +-------------+
```

I want the page to load with the child/scrollable DIV scrolled completely to the left. I have tried RTL hacks, but I can't figure out a good solution.

If this is not the proper place to ask such a question, please feel free to redirect me to such a place.

Comment: AFAIK, I don't think you can do this with pure CSS, without throwing some JS as well.

Comment: It's not quite clear what you're looking for. Is it something like this:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KwMxWo
If not, how is it different from what you're looking for?

Comment: @saesris I think is more like this ... http://codepen.io/anon/pen/emzLWP

Comment: @Danko yeah, I think you're right. I would have called that 'scrolled completely to the right', not left, but I think you did a better job of interpreting what he actually meant.

Comment: Your codepen starts out scrolled to the left.

Comment: @JimWharton check my codepen.

Comment: I'm confused about who you're talking to. @JimWharton, if my codepen was the one that did what you wanted, let me know. Otherwise, I'll assume Danko resolved your issue.

Comment: I wasn't sure, but it seems no JS is needed since, based on these tests: http://jsfiddle.net/Marventus/xh2gozpx/, #scrollable div always loads scrolled to the left.

Comment: My apologies @Danko. I wasn't clear in whom I was addressing. It appears that your codepen does accomplish my goal.